# React Electron two window RDP server folder/app movement

Tags: reactjs, electron, desktop-application, rdp, multiple-monitors

I was created 2 display/window in react electron... for now, I try to move app/folder in one screen to another screen... but it's not working...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IljjV.png)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640030/react-electron-window-full-screen-in-multi-monitors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Electron window full-screen in multi-monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640030/react-electron-window-full-screen-in-multi-monitors)